# for loop setting a var based on checkbox

Tags: php, variables, post, loops

I have a system that allows a user to create a question where each possible answer has a checkbox. If that is checked then that answer is the correct one. I save the `answer_id` in the database, and a TRUE or FALSE value as to whether it is correct or not. However, I am struggling to set the incorrect answers to FALSE since an unset checkbox does not seem to go into the POST.

```
$count = count($_POST['answer']);
$answers = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++) {
    if(isset($_POST['correct'][$i])) {
        $correct = "true";
    } else {
        $correct = "false";
    }
    $answers[] = array(
        'answer' => $_POST['answer'][$i],
        'correct' => $correct
    );
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's totally normal that unchecked boxes are not transferred to the server by your browser. That's why in PHP you don't have these values.

You need to make each checkbox identifiable by giving it a unique name. You can then check if a value of each unique name was transferred. Only those transferred where checked.

So your problem is before the database, you first need to find out which checkboxes were checked and which not.

A simple solution is to number fields, e.g. give them names from `answer_1` to `answer_n` (where `n` is the highest number, e.g. `5`).

If the count of the answers is dynamic, either look for the highest number possible and/or transfer the number of answers in another, hidden form field. Take care you sanitize the input.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="answer_count" value="3" />
    ...
</form>
```

*HTML example of a hidden form field*

```
$name = 'answer';
$count = isset($_POST["$name_count"]) ? max(0, $_POST["$name_count"]) : 0;
$answers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i++ < $count;)
{
    $answer = isset($_POST["$name_$i"]) ? $_POST["$name_$i"] : NULL;
    $correct = /* don't know how you do that, just do it ;) */;
    $answers[] = compact('answer', 'correct');
}
```

*PHP Example to iterate over a set of possibly set form fields*

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Solution build over @hakre's example.
HTML code (each checkbox name contain question index => "answer0", "answer1", ..., "answerN"):

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer0" value="1" /> 2+0=2?
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer1" value="1" /> 2+1=8?
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer2" value="1" /> 2+2=7?
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer3" value="1" /> 2+3=5?
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP code.
`$name` is the constant part of the checbox name which is preceeding the question index.
`$correct_answers` is the array of the correct questions answers (true or false).
In the loop we count the correct answers (`$correct_answers_count`). Correct answer is when the answer is `true` and checkbox is set or when it is `false` and the corresponding checkbox is not set (when you don't check the checbox it is not included to the POST array submitted to the server).

```
$name = 'answer';
$correct_answers = (true, false, false, true);
$answers_count = sizeof($correct_answers);
$correct_answers_count = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i++; $i < $answers_count)
{
    $correct_answers_count += (isset($_POST[$name.(string)$i]) && $correct_answers[$i]) || (!isset($_POST[$name.(string)$i]) && !$correct_answers[$i]) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in the total number of questions also from your form to POST then check against total questions and number of checkboxes set.